# Boost shared memory mapping addresses

Tags: c++, memory, boost, memory-management

When using boost shared memory for inter-process communication there is a question regarding usage of data passed between processes.

These are excerpts from the boost documentation:

> To use shared memory, we have to perform 2 basic steps:
>
> 1. Request to the operating system a memory segment that can be shared between processes. The user can create/destroy/open this memory using a shared memory object: An object that represents memory that can be mapped concurrently into the address space of more than one process..
> 2. Associate a part of that memory or the whole memory with the address space of the calling process. The operating system looks for a big enough memory address range in the calling process' address space and marks that address range as an special range. Changes in that address range are automatically seen by other process that also have mapped the same shared memory object.
>
> If several processes map the same file/shared memory, the mapping address will be surely different in each process. Since each process might have used its address space in a different way (allocation of more or less dynamic memory, for example), there is no guarantee that the file/shared memory is going to be mapped in the same address.
>
> If two processes map the same object in different addresses, this invalids the use of pointers in that memory, since the pointer (which is an absolute address) would only make sense for the process that wrote it. The solution for this is to use offsets (distance) between objects instead of pointers: If two objects are placed in the same shared memory segment by one process, the address of each object will be different in another process but the distance between them (in bytes) will be the same.

The question is that lets assume that the data being written and then read needs to be n-byte aligned (for better CPU performance) then how can this be achieved if each process see's different addresses that actually point to the same data? The writing process can correctly place the data in a certain alignment but the receiving process won't see it as an aligned address.

Comment: Have you been able to get shared memory for inter-process communication to have different alignment in the two processes?

Comment: It depends on `n`. For small `n` it will just work. If you need this guarantee for big `n`, well that becomes an interesting problem

Comment: The alignments can range from 16 up to 256. In practice, the address of the same data is different between the two processes and then the alignment also differs

Comment: No problems then, since that's smaller than a page, and pages are always page-aligned